# Iterator.remove() IllegalStateException

Tags: java, iterator, illegalstateexception

In the code below I have a try catch block that attempts to remove an element from a Vector, using Iterator. I've created my own class `QueueExtendingVect` that extends `Vector` and implements `Iterator`.

The variable `qev1` is an instance of class `QueueExtendingVect`. I've already added a few elements to this Vector as well.

```
try 
{
   qev1.iterator().remove();
}
catch(UnsupportedOperationException e) 
{
   System.out.println("Calling Iterator.remove() and throwing exception.");
}

qev1.enqueue(ci); 
qev2.enqueue(ci);
qcv1.enqueue(ci);
qcv2.enqueue(ci);

for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
   if (i % 2 == 0)
   {
       qev1.enqueue(new CInteger(i+1));
       qev2.enqueue(new CInteger(i+1));
       qcv1.enqueue(new CInteger(i+1));
       qcv2.enqueue(new CInteger(i+1));
   } 
   else 
  { 
       qev1.enqueue(new Date(i*i));
       qev2.enqueue(new Date(i*i));
       qcv1.enqueue(new Date(i*i));
       qcv2.enqueue(new Date(i*i));
   }
}
```

In this code I add a few elements to the Vector qev1. The other variables are in other parts of the code.

However, when I run my program I get an IllegalStateException at runtime. I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: Is it possible there's nothing in your iterator? Please provide more code. Specifically what type is the collection you're iterating across?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You haven't called `next()` on your `Iterator`, so it's not referring to the first item yet.  You can't remove the item that isn't specified yet.

Call `next()` to advance to the first item first, then call `remove()`.

Comment: I've redone the code to include the statement "qev1.iterator().next()" , however I am still getting the same error. Is there any other reason why I may be getting this error?

Comment: @mynorka you create a new iterator with that call. The issues stands. This answer is correct.

Comment: This also happened to me. But the cause wasn't the same, I was calling `it.remove()` twice or more, which will lead to IllegaStateException.

Answer (score 2):

@rgettman answer is correct but to give you imagination.

Our collection: |el1| |el2| |el3|

when you call `iterator.next()` it works this way:

|el1| iterator |el2| |el3|

so it jumps over the element and return reference to the element which was jumped (|el1|). So if we called `iterator.remove()` now, |el1| would be removed.

It's worth to add what @PedroBarros mentioned above - you can't call `iterator.remove()` two times without `iterator.next()` between them because `IllegalStateException` would be thrown.
Also when you create two iterators (iterator1, iterator2) then calling:

```
iterator1.next();
iterator1.remove();
iterator2.next();
```

will throw ConcurrentModificationException because `iterator2` checks that collection was modified.

Answer (score 1):

It will also call this exeption, If you add something to the list in iterator and then after it not calling `it.next()` again but removing the item