# Why the iterator throws a exception for Integer linkedlist

Tags: java, iterator, integer

I would like to understand why the iterator is not working with the next(); for my Integer list. I found a similar question that pointed to my add.All(Arrays.aslist) being the problem. However, I still could not figure out how I should re-write it to work.

It appears this for me:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException
> at java.base/java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.remove(LinkedList.java:927)
> at Iterator_Class.main(Iterator_Class.java:11)

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Iterator_Class {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<String> animals = new LinkedList<String>();
        animals.addAll(Arrays.asList("fox","cat","dog","rabbit"));

        Iterator<String> it = animals.iterator();
        it.remove();
        System.out.println("remove using iterator: " + animals);

        while(it.hasNext()){
            String value = it.next();
            System.out.println(value);
        }

        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Iterator<Integer> i = list.iterator();
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(10,20,30));
        System.out.println(list);
        
        while(i.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(i.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to call `next()` first as `remove()` removes the last item returned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterator.remove() IllegalStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361194/iterator-remove-illegalstateexception)

Comment: Another problem with your code is that you first create an iterator of `list`, then modify `list`, then use the iterator. That is not allowed. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html) for `LinkedList` reads: *The iterators returned by this class's* `iterator` *and* `listIterator` *methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the Iterator's own* `remove` *or* `add` *methods, the iterator will throw a* `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: I figured it out that the problem is using the iterator for more than one list. If I delete the integer or the string it works. Is it possible to use the iterator with multiple lists?